# RLMResults notification block is never called

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I'm trying to get updates whenever certain objects are added to Realm, using a notification block to do so.

```
@interface SessionManager ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) RLMResults<MetaAsset *> *metaAssets;
@property (strong, nonatomic) RLMNotificationToken *notificationToken;

@end

- (void)start
{
    self.metaAssets = [[MetaAsset objectsWhere:@"isValid = YES"] sortedResultsUsingProperty:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
    self.notificationToken = [self.metaAssets addNotificationBlock:^(RLMResults<MetaAsset *> * _Nullable results, RLMCollectionChange * _Nullable change, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSLog(@"received notification");
    }];
    [self addStuffToRealm];
}
```

I've added a breakpoint in `- addStuffToRealm` to check whether or not new `MetaAsset` are appearing in `self.metaAssets`, and they are, but the notification block is never called. Perhaps I've misunderstood what the notification block does?

Thanks!

Comment: Katsumi from Realm here. There id no problem in your code. It should work. Can you share reproducible project or send it to help@realm.io to investigate?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi thanks for the response. I managed to fix it by moving `- addStuffToRealm` to a background thread, since I realised it was blocking. Does that seem like it could have been the problem?

Comment: It depends on implementation of `addStuffToRealm`. Can you show the code of `addStuffToRealm`?

Comment: @kishikawakatsumi it was simply a for loop that creates model objects and adds them to realm using `- transactionWithBlock:` and `- addObject:`. there is nothing special about the code, but it was all taking place on the same dispatch queue (main) and the process of creating the objects is expensive since it involves image processing. it was entirely synchronous. i've now moved the for loop to its own queue and the notifications work as normal. before, the main queue run loop was being blocked.